# Message box based on two Conditions

Tags: vba, if-statement, macros, conditional-statements, messagebox

I need your help again.
I'm trying to create a Message Box based on two Conditions. 
I have two lists:
One with numbers from 1 to 20.
And the second one with: Single Stock, Single Option, Basket of Stocks and Basket of Options.

When choosing Single Stock/Single Option in Sheet "Input" cell "F7", it should be only possible to use the number "1" in cell "F8" otherwise the Message box with error should be displayed.

When choosing Basket of Stocks/Options in Sheet "Input" cell "F7", it should be only possible to use a number >1 in cell "F8" otherwise the Message box with error should be displayed.

I've tried to use this code:

```
Sub Msg_exe()
If Target.Address = "$F$8" Then
  If Target.Value > 2 Then
    If Target.Address = "Stock" Then
      If Target.Address = "Option" Then
        MsgBox "Error!", vbExclamation, "Error"
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

Sub Msg_exe()
If Target.Address = "$F$8" Then
  If Target.Value < 2 Then
    If Target.Address = "Basket of Stocks" Then
      If Target.Address = "Basket of Options" Then
        MsgBox "Error!", vbExclamation, "Error"
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
```

Comment: There are all sorts of issues with the code you posted, first you declare the sub Msg_exe twice which is not supported.  Second you reference Target however there is no variable named Target in either of the method signatures.

Comment: The `.Address` also will never return something like "Stock" and even if it would, you check for two different values so this would never do anything.

Comment: @Sorceri How is it possible to find a solution?
I'm not experienced using VBA that's why I would appreciate any help

Comment: @arcadeprecinct could you tell me how you would do it?

Comment: replace `Target.Adress` and `Target.Value` with wherever your values are (such as `Range("F7").Value`)

Comment: It sounds like you would want to execute this in a `Worksheet_Change` event which would indeed give you a `Target`. You would only use that to check if the change was in a relevant cell though.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Could you show me an example? What does Range do?

Comment: Well i just need a kind of "checking", look at my description above

Comment: Do some research about worksheet events and read some tutorials about Excel VBA (`Range` is one of the most basic and most important things in Excel VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from this code:

```
If Target.Address = "$F$8" Then
    Select Case Range("F7")
        Case "Single Stock", "Single Option"
            If Range("F8").Value <> 1 Then MsgBox "Error!", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Case "Basket of Stocks", "Basket of Options"
            If Range("F8").Value <= 1 Then MsgBox "Error!", vbExclamation, "Error"
    End Select
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use VBA you could just add data validation to cell F8:
`=IF(OR($F$7="Stock",$F$7="Option"),$F$8=1,IF(OR($F$7="Basket of Stocks",$F$7="Basket of Options"),$F$8>1,""))`